# Repeatedly solving linear systems with different diagonal matrix sandwhich

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a series of linear equations to solve:
$$A^\intercal D_1 Ax_1=b_1$$
$$A^\intercal D_2 Ax_2=b_2$$
$$A^\intercal D_3 Ax_3=b_3$$
$$\vdots$$

$A$ is a "tall" matrix, as in it has more rows than columns. Both $A$ and $D_i$ are full rank $\forall i$. $D_i \succ 0$ $\forall i$. Is there a method to solve these systems without doing the full set of matrix multiplications and Gaussian eliminations each time I was thinking some type of setup that one could do on A that would then make this repeated solving a lot faster.

My initial thought was looking for something like $(A^\intercal D_i A)^{-1}=B (D_i)^{-1} B^\intercal$. I would have thought that some type of pseudoinverse could help me, like $B=A^+$, but as far as I can tell $(A^\intercal)^+ A^\intercal \neq I$, so I feel stuck. However, the fact that the middle matrix is diagonal gives me hope since I feel like it still might work because of D only scaling the rows of A.

**Edits from questions in comments:**
From a practical point of view, A is around 50×10 and the number of $D_i$ is around 2x the number of rows. However, this problem got me interested in this from a theoretical standpoint as well, so I'd be happy with an answer that assumes that number of $D_i \gg m$

Edit: I just found this old question, where the author asks a similar question as a subpart to their larger question, but the answer has no solution. [Efficient Algorithm for Iteratively Reweighted Least Squares Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/852327/efficient-algorithm-for-iteratively-reweighted-least-squares-problem)

Comment: Can you give us some rough size of the dimensions of $A$ and the number of matrices $D_i$? Are we assuming $\# D_i \gg \# rows$?

Comment: @JairTaylor From a practical point of view, A is around $50 \times10$ and the number of $D_i$ is around 2x the number of rows. However, this problem got me interested in this from a theoretical standpoint as well, so I'd be happy with an answer that assumes that #$D_i \gg m$

Comment: @whpowell96 I don't understand how the LU helps in the non square case. Would you mind writing it up as an answer? I've never seen a triangle solve with a non square matrix.